# URL changes to *.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ when entering website, do I have a problem?

Tags: malware, account-security, url-redirection

I was browsing for help on how to connect a PS2 controller to my pc. I found what I was looking for here:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262873/do-playstation-2-controllers-support-usb-connections
In the second comment he linked to a site with a guide. I right clicked and copied like a always do for safety, and pasted it in to the url bar. It showed this URL which seemed legit: http://store.curiousinventor.com/guides/PS2.
But when I entered it the url changed to this: 
http://ec2-50-16-216-49.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
I am wondering if this is some form of malware that redirected me or if is it safe? 
I just recently reinstalled windows and I have avast antivirus and windows defender on, nothing popped up. I use Brave browser if that is to any help.

I do not know if this is the correct place to ask this question, but I'm paranoid and couldn't find a better place...

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: If you see that, it simply means the site you are visiting is hosted at Amazon Web Services.  That's the "aws" part.  They also host the CIA, in case you need a reason to be paranoid.  ;-)   All true, but that was a joke.  They are just a large hosting provider, trusted by the best..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nah, it's fine on your end— just an HTTP redirect. See below...

```
curl -v http://store.curiousinventor.com/guides/PS2
*   Trying 50.16.216.49...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to store.curiousinventor.com (50.16.216.49) port 80 (#0)
> GET /guides/PS2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: store.curiousinventor.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sat, 14 Apr 2018 20:18:12 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.27
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Location: http://ec2-50-16-216-49.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80/
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host store.curiousinventor.com left intact
```

EDIT: That said, it doesn’t seem like that has anything to do with what you were looking for, so their website may have been compromised.